# Openlayers: Parsing GeoJSON-properties results in a "data"-property in feature

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I'm using OpenLayers 2.12.

I try to load a GeoJSON-response from server and (nearly) everything works fine: but the properties contained in the GeoJSON-response ("nummer" and "befund" below) were put in a data-attribute of the feature-objects, not in their attributes-property, which I would expect. As observed in firebug, in the attributes-property I only find the names of my properties and empty strings as values.

Did I miss something, some parameters when creating the formatter or something like that? It's ugly to copy the values in every feature back to attributes...

My parsing function:

```
function parseGeoJson(featuresText) {                   
    var formatter = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
    var features = formatter.read(featuresText);                
    if (features.length > 0) {
        editor.editLayer.addFeatures(features);
    }
}
```

My GeoJson:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[
    {"type":"Feature",
     "properties":
          {"nummer":"1",
           "befund":"1.1.1"},
     "geometry":{
          "type":"Polygon",
          "coordinates":[
              [[15.37109375,81.11328125],[65.29296875,86.38671875],
             [36.11328125,58.7890625],[15.37109375,81.11328125]]]
      }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personnally, I need more input.

I maybe misunderstand but it seems to works: I mean I see your geoJSON properties within the `data` and `attributes` keys with the values in the debugger complete.

I use below code in Firebug at http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/draw-feature.html

```
var featuresText = '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature", "properties":{"nummer":"1","befund":"1.1.1"}, "geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[15.37109375,81.11328125],[65.29296875,86.38671875],[36.11328125,58.7890625],[15.37109375,81.11328125]]]}}]}';
var formatter = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
var features = formatter.read(featuresText);
console.log(features);
```

To confirm I (do not) understand your viewpoint, you will also see a screenshot of the object [image: OpenLayers.Feature.vector content]

Comment: As ThomasG77 says, I can't see any issue. Your geojson is valid and the properties appear as attributes.